# 各約数の出力について

Tags: python, python3

各約数を入力して、出力では約数の合計を出力するプログラム作成してまして
現在ですと、最後に入力された値のみしか出力されません。
どうすれば、各入力値に対する出力をすることが出来ますか？

```
N = int(input())
sum_list = []
num_list = []
for _ in range(N):
    num = int(input())

divisor = [i for i in range(1, num) if num % i == 0]
divisor_list = list(divisor)
sum_divisor_list = sum(divisor_list)
print(sum_divisor_list)
```

目的

入力値
3
28
16
10

出力
28
15
8

ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 申し訳ないのですが、質問の内容が曖昧です。

Comment: 質問内容が曖昧で申し訳ございません。コメント内容を参考にしてみます！ありがとうございます。

Comment: 結局の所、素因数分解なのか約数なのか、どちらなのでしょう？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！約数です！

Comment: 質問内容修正致しました。勘違いを抱く質問をしてしまい大変ご迷惑をおかけしました。以後気をつけます。

Answer (score 0):

「後に入力された値のみしか出力され」ない理由はfor文の中でN回`num`を書き換えているため、それ以前の入力値を消して上書きしていることが原因です。

ご質問の意図が「特定の数値の(素数ではなく)約数をすべて求め、その約数(ただし特定の数値自体は除く)を合計すること」であり、`divisor`の定義以降の処理が正しいと仮定した場合は下記のようにコードを書きなおすことができます。

**修正例**

```
N = int(input())  # 3 を入力
for _ in range(N):
    num = int(input("> ")) # 3回のループでそれぞれ 28, 16, 10 を入力

    divisor = [i for i in range(1, num // 2 + 1) if num % i == 0] # Tips 約数を求めるならばnumの半分までループすれば良い
    divisor_list = list(divisor)
    sum_divisor_list = sum(divisor_list)
    print(divisor_list)     # 約数の確認用コード
    print(sum_divisor_list) # 求める出力
```

**出力結果**

```
3
> 28
[1, 2, 4, 7, 14]
28
> 16
[1, 2, 4, 8]
15
> 10
[1, 2, 5]
8
```

Comment: 約数だとすれば num 自身も約数になりますので、`divisor_list` に追加する必要があります。

Comment: @metropolis ご指摘ありがとうございます。`その約数(ただし特定の数値自体は除く)`と表現を改めました。

Comment: コメント及びコードありがとうございます。とても参考になります。
今後も勉強を続けて行きます

Answer (score 0):

[SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) というパッケージに `proper_divisors()` という関数があります。

[sympy.ntheory.factor_.proper_divisors](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html#sympy.ntheory.factor_.proper_divisors)

> Return all divisors of n except n, sorted by default.

質問文にあるコードには `num_list` というリストがあるので、それを使いましょう(`sum_list`も)。

```py
from sympy import proper_divisors

num_list = []
N = int(input())
for _ in range(N):
  num_list.append(int(input()))

sum_list = []
for num in num_list:
  sum_divisors = sum(proper_divisors(num))
  print(sum_divisors)
  sum_list.append(sum_divisors)
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そんなライブラリーがあったんですね。
始めて知りました。とても参考になります。ありがとうございます。